# Storing Key and Value using Javascript in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a jsp page on which table is coming dynamically and have checkboxes on that page when you click on that box it should save in array and when it uncheck the box it should remove value from array.

I have tried this by creating a method but it is not working perfectly can you please help me..

```
function addCheckboxVAlues(checked){
    var split = checked.value.split("|");
    var key =split[0];
    var value=split[1];
    var chks = $("input[name='"+key+"']:checked");
      if (chks.length > 0)  {
         uninvoiced.push(value);
      } else {
         uninvoiced.pop(key);
      }
      console.log(uninvoiced);
}
```

Comment: `uninvoiced.pop(key);` - array pop method removes teh last element of the array - look at other methods to find and remove elements in an array - or use an object instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to use splice to remove the element from the array

```
function addCheckboxVAlues(checked){
    var split = checked.value.split("|");
    var key =split[0];
    var value=split[1];
    var chks = $("input[name='"+key+"']:checked");
    var index = uninvoiced.indexOf(key);
      if (chks.length > 0)  {
         uninvoiced.push(value);
      } else if(index > -1){
         uninvoiced.splice(index, 1);
      }
      console.log(uninvoiced);
}
```

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

Comment: Uninvoiced is an array and do we have indexOf method for array..? We do not have map in JavaScript?

Comment: Array has prototype method indexOf. You can check the entire list of prototype methods associated with array in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Comment: Note that `IE<9 doesn't support indexOf`

Comment: You could polyfill the indexOf method to make it work in all browser versions

Answer (score 0):

This code looks way more complex than it needs to be. Presumably the checkbox has a click listener on it, so it should be called with the checkbox as *this*. All you have to do is add the value if the checkbox is checked, or remove it if it's unchecked.

That will be hugely more efficient than running a *checked* selector every time.

The following uses an inline listener for convenience, likey you're attaching them dynamically but it seems to be called the same way.

```js
var uninvoiced = [];
function addCheckbox(el) {
  var value = el.value.split('|')[1];
  if (el.checked) {
    uninvoiced.push(value);
  } else {
    uninvoiced.splice(uninvoiced.indexOf(value), 1);
  }
  console.log(uninvoiced);
}
```

```html
foo|bar: <input type="checkbox" value="foo|bar" onclick="addCheckbox(this)">
fee|fum: <input type="checkbox" value="fee|fum" onclick="addCheckbox(this)">
```

There is a polyfill for [*indexOf* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Thank you for the reply RobG... it is working perfect... Can you please tell me how can i get value of units on basis of this value... <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"units\" style=\"width:25px;\" id=\""+6167+"\" value=\"1\" ")

Comment: The controls are probably in a form, form controls have a reference to the form by their *form* property. The form has a reference to all its controls by name, so within the function you can do `el.form.units.value`. If there are more than one control with a name of *units* then referencing them by name returns a collection, to get the value of the first one use `el.form.units[0].value` and so on for the rest.

Comment: @ RobG thank you for your help i did this in the same way.. now m able to choose result from single click but this code is not working if i m using multiple clicks..

Comment: It works for me. It includes only the checked ones, any that are unchecked are removed no matter how many times I click on each.

Comment: How can i split values like 24,23,25 into a=24,b=25,c=23 using java script.... as javascript have function called split but it adds comma not removes....

Comment: @user12495— [*String.prototype.split*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.split) creates an array based on splitting the string on the provided characters or regular expression. It does not add commas, they are are a result of the default [*Array.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring) function which uses `join(',')`. Your OP only asks to split to two values. If you want more, then ask another question with what you actually want.